# Is it the correct use of "take hold"?

Tags: grammar, usage

Societies are based on laws.In past, before laws **took hold** in the human communities, there was no society.

Furthermore can we say :

In past, before laws **take hold** in the human communities, there was no society.

Comment: The article is required in *in **the** past*, but idiomatically unacceptable in *in **the** communities*. Your second example must be ***took** hold* (past tense) because obviously you're *talking* about the past. Concentrate on basic tense and article usage before you start looking at phrasal verbs like *to take hold*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/take+hold) take hold means:

> to become established.

As such, your sentence reads:

> In the past, before laws became established in human communities, there was no society.

Regarding your example:

> In the past, before laws take hold in human communities, there was no society.

You cannot use present tense next to the word **past** which requires a past tense. Furthermore, putting present tense as taking place before past tense (there was no society) makes no sense.

Also, as Fumble Fingers points out in his comment you must take care of the use of the definite article **the**.